# In a single web-container how many different web-applications can be run?

Tags: java

I like to know in a single web-container how many different web-applications can be run?
As I like to know the memory constraint of web container.

Comment: How long is a piece of string? Seriously, what sort of answer do you think we can give?

Comment: This person has been asking bizarre, poorly worded questions all day

Comment: Bhozo has answered to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default memory to the servlet container is the default memory of the JVM, which differs between JVMs. The latest Sun JVM I think has `-Xmx` set to 65mb, but I'm not sure.

For Tomcat, you can increase this memory to whatever value you like (together with `-Xms`) by setting it in the catalina.bat / catalina.sh. (for "Where exactly" - google it. I think it was `CATALINA_OPTS`).

To answer your question - there is no limit to the number of applications run in a container.